# How to centre a table wihthout textwidth lines?

Tags: tables

I have the following table which I want it to be in the centre of a two column document. But I want to table horizontal lines to be reduced so that they are aligned with the table content width and not the page width. Here is a screen shot and the script.

[image]

The script:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,10pt]{article}

%table
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs} %for the table
\usepackage{pifont}% cross and match marks. http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%


\begin{document}

\begin{table*} [t!] \centering
  \centering

  \label{tab:table1}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lcccc} %{\columnwidth}{cccccc}
    \toprule
                                      & col1  & col2  & col3  \\ %& Secure key  & \textit{VRF} Waiting Time\\
    \midrule
      row1                & \cmark             & \cmark        & \cmark        \\   %& \\
      row2                       & \cmark             & \cmark         & \cmark        \\  %& \\
      row3  &                 &                & \cmark        \\   %&    \\   

    %prettifies & the & content \\

    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}

\caption{table.}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: the lines are just over long as the input is in error tabularx has to have X columns, but here just use `\begin{tabular}{lcccc}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Another example of `tabularx` misuse :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX I blame the author of the package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, it must be package author's fault! Hahahaha

Comment: To generate quickly a complex LaTeX tables online, you can use the generator http://www.tablesgenerator.com/ or a plugin for Ex­cel at link https://www.ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex without mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

Best solution: Do not use `tabularx` with `\textwidth` if you do not want this. Especially if you do not have `X` column `tabularx` cannot work (see manual).

Besides that you should:

1. Do not use `\centering` twice.
2. Use `\label` after `\caption`.

Here's a working version:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twocolumn,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs} %for the table
\usepackage{pifont}% cross and match marks. http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t!]
  \centering

\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
    \toprule
                                      & col1  & col2  & col3  \\ 
    \midrule
      row1                & \cmark             & \cmark        & \cmark        \\  
      row2                       & \cmark             & \cmark         & \cmark        \\ 
      row3  &                 &                & \cmark        \\

    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

\caption{table.}\label{tab:table1}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```